# Using timestamp to divide a list based on month Python

Tags: python, list, datetime, timestamp

I want to map timestamps list according to their month number `1` to `12`:

For example with list of timestamps:

```
[1231469744, 1231470173, 1231470988, 1231471428, 1545730073]
```

Should be:

```
{1: [1231469744, 1231470173, 1231470988, 1231471428], 12: [1545730073]}
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck…?

Comment: I'm stuck in in two step: First if i need to create something that contains just the months (a list of months one to one with the timestamp, or a dictionary)  or if exist an automatic method, and also with the best package to use to do all the procedure

Comment: @DuccioBorchi Have you seen my edit?, think this is what you aiming for.

Comment: Yes I tried the code now and it works thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map them:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

timestamps = [1231469744, 1231470173, 1231470988, 1231471428]
months_dict = defaultdict(list)
for timestamp in timestamps:
    months_dict[datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).month].append(timestamp)
print(dict(months_dict))
```

Output:

```
{1: [1231469744, 1231470173, 1231470988, 1231471428], 12: [1545730073]}
```